# Select to search column on group by query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table called **prices** that have a reference from table products through **product_id** column. I want a query that selects prices grouped by *product_id* with the max final date and get the value of start_date through one select with id of price grouped.

I try with the following query but I am getting a wrong value of start date. Is weird because of the result subquery return more than one row even though I use the price id on where clause. Because that I put the limit on the query but it is wrong.

```
select prices.produto_id, prices.id, 
MAX(CASE WHEN prices.finish_date IS NULL THEN COALESCE(prices.finish_date,'9999-12-31') ELSE prices.finish_date END) as finish_date, 
(select start_date from prices where prices.id = prices.id limit 1) 
 as start_date from prices group by prices.product_id, prices.id
```

How I can get the relative start date of the price id in my grouped row? I am using postgresql.

A example to view what I want with my query:

DataSet:

```
ID | PRODUCT_ID | START_DATE          | FINISH_DATE
1    1689         2018-01-19 02:00:00   2019-11-19 23:59:59
2    1689         2019-10-11 03:00:00   2019-10-15 23:59:59
3    1689         2019-01-11 03:00:00   2019-05-15 23:59:59
4    1690         2019-11-11 03:00:00   2019-12-15 23:59:59
5    1690         2019-05-11 03:00:00   2025-12-15 23:59:59
6    1691         2019-05-11 03:00:00   null
```

I want this result:

```
ID | PRODUCT_ID | START_DATE          | FINISH_DATE
1    1689         2018-01-19 02:00:00   2019-11-19 23:59:59
5    1690         2019-05-11 03:00:00   2025-12-15 23:59:59
6    1691         2019-05-11 03:00:00   9999-12-31 23:59:59
```

The start date should be the same value of the row before the group by.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify your question.

Comment: Ok. I added this informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `DISTINCT ON` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (p.product_id) p.*
from prices p
order by p.product_id,
         p.finish_date desc nulls first;
```

`NULL` values are treated as larger than any other value, so a descending sort puts them first.  However, I've included `nulls first` just to be explicit.

`DISTINCT ON` is a very handy Postgres extension, which you can learn more about in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with data as (
 SELECT id, product_id,
 max(COALESCE(finish_date,'9999-12-31')) as finish_date from prices group by 1,2)  
select d.*, p.start_date from data d join prices p on p.id = d.id;
```

It surely isnt' the most elegant solution, but it should work.